# How to add additional Routes dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular5, angular-router

I'm using Angular 5.2.2 (typescript) with Angular-CLI and .NET Core 2.0.

I'm trying to add additional Routes dynamically to my application.

The idea is that I get my routes dynamically from a server which checks what modules should be available to the user.
But I cant seem to get the routes to become available.

I've tried to add them using `RouterModule.forRoot` but that did not work.

I've tried using `Router.resetConfig` but I can't seem to get that working.
I try to use dependency injection to get it in the function I've created but I end up with a cyclic dependency:

```
Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

Here is a bit of the code I have:

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

var routes: Routes = [{ path: '', loadChildren: "../app/modules/f2p-dashboard/f2p-dashboard.module#F2PDashboardModule" }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: AppConfigServiceFactory,
      deps: [F2PModuleService, Router ],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export function AppConfigServiceFactory(moduleService: F2PModuleService, 
router:Router) {
  return () => {
    return moduleService.Init().subscribe((result) => {
      let additionalRoutes = moduleService.GetRoutes()
      routes = routes.concat(additionalRoutes);
      console.log(routes);
      //routes is filled
  router.resetConfig(routes);
  //RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
});
```

edit:
All the routes I'm trying to add make use of `loadChildren`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842536/implementing-dynamic-routing-in-angular2-typescript  you can refer this, if this help

Comment: Thank you for your response,

Comment: Those solutions are deprecated, the comments state another solution but that also seems deprecated (or perhaps its a bug in Angular)
So its not an answer to my problems.
Even so thank you for your response

Comment: @D Berg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928030/is-it-possible-to-build-add-routes-dynamically-in-angular-2 this will definitely help you..!

Comment: Thank you for your response, its been a while since ive last responded.
Ive been busy with other tasks in the meantime. As i couldnt get this to work.
Im not going to invest more time in this problem for now. Thank your for your help though.

Answer (score 15):

One of the ways to do this is by pushing the route into the router and using resetConfig.

```
Example :
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
   const config = this.router.config;
   config.push({
            path: 'dynamicRoutePath',
            component: DynamicRouteComponent,
        });
        this.router.resetConfig(config);
        this.router.navigate(['dynamicRoutePath'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

This should work.